# How do I write file modification dates programmatically in POSIX?

Tags: c, unix, file, posix

I would like to *touch* my files from C code to modify their access date.   This does not seem to work:

```
struct stat fileSt;
lstat(path, &fileSt);
fileSt.st_mtime = time(NULL);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you want `utime(2)`. That should be enough:

```
utime(filename, NULL);
```

The docs say:

> ```
> int utime(const char *filename, const struct utimbuf *times);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The  utime()  system call changes the access and modification times of the
>   inode specified by filename to the actime  and  modtime  fields  of  times
>   respectively.
>
> If  times  is `NULL`, then the access and modification times of the file are
>   set to the current time.

Answer (score 14):

[utimes()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/utimes.2.html) is probably how to do it.  utime() is obsolete.

Things like this are trivial to determine using tools like strace.

```
strace touch -t 01010911 xxx
.
.
open("xxx", O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 0
utimes("/proc/self/fd/0", {1230829860, 0}) = 0
```

Comment: I believe strace is Linux-specific and the OP did not mention which UNIX he used (Solaris, FreeBSD, etc, have similar commands but not strace).

Comment: Oddly, POSIX marks utimes() as legacy, even though it provides more functionality than utime()

Comment: @Chris Not anymore. According to Issue 7 "The LEGACY marking is removed.". Source: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/futimens.html

Comment: Note that `utimensat()` is the newest version which allows for a `timespec` (nanoseconds precision), just like `stat(2)` returns (see `st_mtim` opposed to `st_mtime`—notice the last letter difference). troglobit has the right answer.

Answer (score 7):

The old `utime()` and `utimes()` are OK for many use-cases, but to update `atime` & `mtime` with *nanosecond resolution*, which you need on modern systems, use:

```
utimensat(0, path, NULL, 0);
```

This is very useful in combination with newer `stat()` which returns a `struct timespec` `st_mtim` field in `struct stat` with nanosecond resolution as well.

Comment: This answer is almost correct, but instead of 0 as the first argument one should use AT_FDCWD. Also, the third argument is an array of 2 timespec structs.

Comment: It is of course always a good idea to read the manual to a command you've never used before instead of just cut-and-paste.  The first argument should be `AT_FDCWD` if path is relative and the third argument can be `NULL`, at least on GLIBC systems, and will then default to the current time, like `touch(1)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at the utime()/utimes() system call.